# Facebook SDK login delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the latest Facebook SDK for iOS.

I have a `FBLoginView` in my "login" screen but there only seems to be a `FBLoginViewDelegate`. Can I not set a delegate on the `FBSession` like I used to be able to?

I want to catch actual login to Facebook. Not just the `FBLoginView` changing to show "Log Out" as this happens every time the app opens even if the user was already logged in and the access token was valid.

Answer (score 1):

put this code to log out manually

```
 FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
    [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [session close];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/"]];

    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```

also u add this code:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 IOS 10!

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

}
```